# Display WordPress Custom Taxonomy Child Term and then Parent Term

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

In WordPress I have a `country_category` custom taxonomy used which has a country/region as a Parent Term and a state/province/country as a Child Term like so:

```
United States, Florida
United States, California

Europe, Sweden
Europe, Germany etc
```

I am finding on output the order can vary depending on the Parent Term, I want the child term to appear first but my output varies it is:

```
United States, Florida
United States, California

Sweden, Europe
Germany, Europe
```

So above the United States hierarchy is incorrect but the Europe one displays correctly.
How can I force the child term to always **appear first**

I have tried get_the_term_list:

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( get_the_id(), 'country_category',  "<p>" ,"</p>" ); ?>
```

but find that term order varies.

Answer (score 0):

So the inconsistency is down to the **term_order** number as set in the **wp_terms** table.

I needed to set some parent terms with a higher integer - then the order is displayed correctly.